# Create collection of elements based on types listed in another collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net

**Background**

I'm using .NET 5 and Quartz.NET. I wanna make many jobs with triggers (but individual for every job). Example code to creating job:

```cs
IJobDetail newJob = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "myGroup")
    .Build();
```

`MyJob` is class containing `Execute` method with code to execute as a job. I have many classes like this. I want to create generic method in order to create new jobs from a list containing classes as types (or in different way, I'm open to suggestions).

Pseudocode of my concept:

```cs
foreach(Type t in types)
{
   IJobDetail newJob = JobBuilder.Create<t>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "myGroup")
    .Build();
}
```

**Question**

My question is: is there any way to do this? I saw threads on Stack about making `List` with type from collection like that but I couldn't adapt it to my code. I really don't wanna repeat code like that, because I'm not gonna configure these jobs too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It seems like Quartz.NET shares method to use Type variable in job constructor: `.OfType(Type type)`.

```
IJobDetail newJob = JobBuilder.Create()
    .OfType(jobType)
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "myGroup")
    .Build();
```